# Lambda "cannot be inferred from the usage"

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the following dictionary declared:

```
private readonly Dictionary<int, Image> dictionary;
```

And I have a method, which is causing a compiler error:

```
    public IQueryable<Image> Find(Func<Image, bool> exp)
    {
        return  dictionary.Single(exp);
    }
```

The error i get is:

```
Error   1   The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Single<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,bool>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. C:\work\MSD-AIDS-Images\MSD-AIDS-Images-Test\TestImageRepository.cs 34  30  MSD-AIDS-Images-Test
```

I have tried googling around, I cant seem to find anything definitive as to what I am doing wrong

Edit - This is monday morning at work.

I meant to put "where", not single

**Edit 2!**

Ok, the code is now this:

```
public IQueryable<Image> Find(Func<Image, bool> exp)
{
    return dictionary.Values.Where(exp);
}
```

Now I get the following error:

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MSD_AIDS_Images_Data.Image>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<MSD_AIDS_Images_Data.Image>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)    C:\work\MSD-AIDS-Images\MSD-AIDS-Images-Test\TestImageRepository.cs 34  20  MSD-AIDS-Images-Test
```

As an FYI, the method there is for implementing an interface, the declaration for that is:

```
IQueryable<T> Find(Func<T, bool> exp);
```

This has got more complicated than it should be!

Comment: As I already said - change the return type to IEnumerable<Image>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is it you are trying to do? For example, `Single` will return an instance of `T`, not an `IQueryable<T>` (and for objects, you should probably be using `IEnumerable<T>` anyway)...

It feels like you want:

```
public Image Find(Func<Image, bool> predicate)
{
    return dictionary.Values.Single(predicate);
}
```

Of course, you could do this globally as an extension method via something like:

(**edit** includes `Where` from question edit)

```
static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static TValue FindSingle<TKey, TValue>(
        this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary,
        Func<TValue, bool> predicate)
    {
        return dictionary.Values.Single(predicate);
    }
    public static IEnumerable<TValue> Find<TKey, TValue>(
        this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary,
        Func<TValue, bool> predicate)
    {
        return dictionary.Values.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

(I'm not sure it is much harder for the caller to do this themselves, though)

Comment: The .values bit is what I needed really, so you get the answer. I have edited my question to clarify what I was going for

Comment: Note that with Where you'd typically return IEnumerable<Image> etc - glad you got it sorted, though ;-p

Answer (score 3):

> An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

There are two `Where` methods, one on [System.Linq.Enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) (which it is using), and one on [System.Linq.Queryable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040.aspx) (which you think it should be using, according to that return type).

You need to do one of the following:

- change the return type to `IEnumerable<Image>`  - I recommend this!
- change the method call to `Queryable.Where(dictionary.Values.AsQueryable(), exp)`
- call `AsQueryable()`

Answer (score 2):

`IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>`, so your `Func` should look more like `Func<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>`.